# Having difficulty ignoring case sensitivity for do while loop

Tags: java, loops, case

Trying to let the user exit the program using the letter 'N' or 'n' but it will only let them exit when using 'N'

Below is my code, any help is appreciated!!

```
        System.out.print(" Do you want to repeat the ");
        System.out.println("program ['Y' or 'N']");
        Choice = sc.next().charAt(0);

    } while (Choice != 'N' || Choice != 'n');
}
}
```

Comment: When is `(Choice != 'N' || Choice != 'n')` ever `false`?

Comment: You probably wanted "not N _and_ not n"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `while (Choice != 'N' && Choice != 'n');` .
It must be `AND` condition. Not an `OR` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator:

```
while (Choice != 'N' && Choice != 'n');
```

Right now, your code states that the loop will continue when the character is either not 'N' or not 'n'. Since the character can't be 'N' and 'n' at the same time, the loop will always continue. Switching the operator to a `&&` requires that the character is *neither* `N` nor `n` to continue.